# Counting Available Days in a Row

Tags: excel, count, row

I'm trying to calculate the **number of consecutive available days** I can schedule my drivers.  The schedule I've included shows a date range of 12 days, starting with the day prior.  I've tried everything I know but haven't had any luck.  For analysis purposes I've boxed and highlighted the "available days" and included a column titled "desired results".  The total driver counts are in the hundreds and the future available days are interrupted by other activity on a driver's schedule.  My need is to count the blank slots that start *today* and end with the first populated cell on that driver's schedule (by row).

[image: Data Snapshot]

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, define what makes a day *available*, and then you can count how many cells meet those requirementes defined.

Comment: And perhaps explain why some of the rows with blank cells should return 0.

Comment: An available day is null or empty.  Intervening cells that are populated represent time that is already scheduled, days off, or truck maintenance.  Subsequent null values represent future availability.  My immediate needs is to calculate the number of days a driver is available to determine which routes I can plot on their schedule.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I'm afraid it is still unclear to us. For example, row 2, why 31-Oct - 3-Nov is not counted? Or rows 6, 7 and 9 - why these return 0? You wrote that "subsequent null values represent future availability", but all those dates are already in the past. Further clarification will help us understand your problem.

Comment: Those days are already scheduled.  The need is to calculate the number of empty cells, beginning with today and ending with the first populated cell.  That number represents the number of days a diver is available to service a route.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand, you want to count the number of blank cells beginning in column B until the next populated cell in each row, the following formula will help you achieve your desired results:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:L2="",0),0)=1,MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(B2:L2="",0),0)<>1),MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(B2:L2="",0),0)-1,0),0)
```

In essence the formula will check if the first Cell in the range (ie. Column B) is blank, then it will check for the first non blank cell in the row, and then give you the results, all this is wrapped in an IFERROR to convert errors to 0.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you want to count how many empty cells are in each row, columns B:L, until first non empty cell is found:

[image]

My formula in M2 is:

`=MATCH("*";B2:L2;0)-1`

Drag it down and hope you can adapt it to your needs.